# python argparse store --foo=bar as args.key='foo', args.value='bar'

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to parse a command line that has a mutually exclusive group of options.  Normally, I'd just use `--foo bar` which would produce, in the namespace, `args.foo = 'bar'`

However, since all of these options are mutually exclusive, and I'm interested in both the option name and the argument passed to the option, and I have several of these options that need to be fed downstream, what I'd really like is to get back `args.option_name = 'foo', args.option_value = 'bar'` in my namespace instead of `args.foo='bar'`.

What I've done is:

```
class KeyAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values) 
        setattr(namespace, self.dest+'_key', option_string)

frob = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
frob.add_argument('--foo', dest='thing', nargs='?', action=KeyAction)
frob.add_argument('--nar', dest='thing', nargs='?', action=KeyAction)
```

when run, my namespace will look like:

```
Namespace(thing_key='--foo', thing='bar')
```

when `--foo=bar` is parsed.  Of course, sadly, if --foo or --nar is never passed in, `namespace.thing_key` doesn't get defined, so I have to use a `getattr()`.

The action override, while functional, doesn't seem really right.

I suspect the brilliant minds behind argparse already got this right somehow, and I'm just missing it in the documentation and from my
read of argparse.py.

What's the best, right, pythonic, way to do this?  Subparsers?
I'm using python 3.5.

So I ended up using data from both of your answers to construct this, which handles the option, it's argument, and sets everything sanely at initialization time.

Thank you very much for the hints, clues, and validation.  I'm surprised this hasn't come up in argparse before and become something standardized.  It *is* a corner case, but isn't that much of a corner case **when using mutually exclusive options**.

```
    class ValueAction(argparse.Action):
        """Override to store both the format type as well as the argument"""
        # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
            self._dest = dest
            dest = dest + '_arguments'
            container = kwargs.pop('container')
            kwargs['action'] = kwargs.pop('subaction')
            action_class = container._pop_action_class(kwargs)
            if not callable(action_class):
                raise ValueError('unknown action "%s"' % (action_class,))
            self._action = action_class(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)
            super().__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            self._action(parser, namespace, values, option_string)
            if isinstance(option_string, str):
                while option_string[0] in parser.prefix_chars:
                    option_string = option_string[1:]
            setattr(namespace, self._dest, option_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing `Action` is exactly what the developers expect you to do.  Even the default, most common action, 'store' is a subclass, `argparse._StoreAction`.  `argparse._StoreTrueAction` is a subclass of `argparse._StoreConstAction`, differing only in the `default` and `const` defaults.

To deal with the missing attribute case you could initialize them in a couple of ways:

`set_defaults` lets you define any defaults, regardless of whether any arguments use them or not.  In the documentation that is used to add function objects to the namespace when using subparsers.

```
parser.set_defaults(thing_key=None, thing=None)
```

You could also create a namespace with the defaults, and pass that as an 
argument to `parse_args`.

```
myNamespace = argparse.Namespace(thing_key=None, thing=None)
parser.parse_args(names=myNamespace)
```

If you don't want a `foo=None` default in the namespace, define its default as `argparse.SUPPRESS`.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you would like to be able to specify a composite action so that you both save the option name used in one Namespace slot and have the updates for some other action performed. E.g., you want to be able to write something like:

```
group = argparse.mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--foo', action=StoreOption, subaction='store_true')
group.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', action=StoreOption, subaction='store')
```

The action class is `StoreOption`, but it will call the action specified by `subaction` to perform additional updates to the Namespace object.

The code I got working (with very limited testing) is shown below:

```
import argparse

class StoreOption(argparse.Action):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['action'] = kwargs.pop('subaction')
    container = kwargs.pop('container')

    action_class = container._pop_action_class(kwargs)
    if not callable(action_class):
      raise ValueError('unknown action "%s"' % (action_class,))

    kwargs['dest'] = 'thing'
    self._action = action_class(**kwargs)
    print "_action:", self._action

    super(StoreOption, self).__init__(
        option_strings= self._action.option_strings,
        dest= self._action.dest,
        nargs= self._action.nargs,
        const= self._action.const,
        default= self._action.default,
        type= self._action.type,
        choices= self._action.choices,
        required= self._action.required,
        help= self._action.help,
        metavar= self._action.metavar)

  def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    print "got here:", option_string, namespace
    setattr(namespace, 'key', option_string)
    self._action(parser, namespace, values, option_string)
```

A test:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--foo', container=group, action=StoreOption, subaction='store_true')
group.add_argument('--bar', container=group, nargs=2, action=StoreOption, subaction='store')

print parser.parse_args(['--bar', 'asd', 'qwe'])
-- prints: Namespace(key='--bar', thing=['asd', 'qwe'])
```

Basically `StoreOption` is an Action which wraps another Action (the one specified by `subaction`). When adding arguments you need to pass the `container=` parameter so that it can construct the sub-action. Also, there is some fiddling with the keyword arguments to set them up correctly for the sub-action.

Again, this has undergone very limited testing, so it may not work for all sub-actions, but it should point you in the right direction.