# Parsing "python foo.py -DVAR1=9 -DVAR2=Off" with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36170308/1270789), I could do this:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-D',action='append',help='FOO=BAR')
options = parser.parse_args('-DVAR1=9 -DVAR2=Off'.split())
```

And I get:

```
Namespace(D=['VAR1=9', 'VAR2=Off'])
```

So then saying:

```
[o.split('=') for o in options.D]
```

Results in:

```
[['VAR1', '9'], ['VAR2', 'Off']]
```

This is basically what I need, but I feel this is a common action that might already have an implementation within the `ArgParse` package. Is there a more Pythonesque way of doing this?

Comment: Use `sys.argv`, which option running first or which option include others ? I am never used this module, maybe i am not use this basically.

Comment: Don't think so. However, a dict of vars might be more useful than a list: `vars=dict( [o.split('=') for o in options.D] )`

Comment: Something similar is implemented in the Figura project.  See [this](https://github.com/shx2/figura/blob/master/figura/cli.py#L57)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `argparse` developers (and other POSIX style parsers) expect you to define `--dvar1` and `--dvar2` arguments, rather than this open ended approach.

Others have asked about some sort of general `key=value` input.  There's nothing in `argparse` that handles that directly.  So collecting the strings as you do and splitting them after parsing looks fine.  What you are doing is as clean and clear as anything I've seen.

You could do that splitting on-the-fly with a `type` function:

```
In [38]: import argparse
In [39]: def foo(astr):
    ...:     return astr.split('=')
    ...: 
In [40]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [41]: parser.add_argument('-D',action='append',type=foo)
Out[41]: _AppendAction(option_strings=['-D'], dest='D', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<function foo at 0xab0c765c>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [42]: options = parser.parse_args('-DVAR1=9 -DVAR2=Off'.split())
In [43]: options
Out[43]: Namespace(D=[['VAR1', '9'], ['VAR2', 'Off']])
```

[python argparse store --foo=bar as args.key='foo', args.value='bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018928/python-argparse-store-foo-bar-as-args-key-foo-args-value-bar)

takes a different approach - subclassing `Action`.  That would be needed if you wanted

```
namespace(VAR1='9', VAR2='Off')
```

(your post processing loop could have written attributes like that to the `namespace`.  Yet another customization trick is to define a custom `Namespace` class, one that can take the `VAR1=9` string and split it as needed.